# Combine records based on criteria

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I currently have a set of about 6k records that include shipment information. The fields are

Miles traveled, volume, ID, Origin City/State/Zip, Destination City/State/Zip, Min Weight, Max Weight, and Equipment Type (for the transportation).

For the equipment type, everything is split up based on what type it is. However, I need to combine the fields that have all of the same criteria (miles traveled, ID, origin, destination, etc.) that are either "FT" or "SD" (two of the types of equipment type.

I can write an IIF statement to make the field "FT-SD" if it's one or the other, but it doesnt combine the field and remove duplicates into one records if, for example, there is one record with SD and one with FT.

I would then need another field that has % of FT and % of SD.

So, for example, lets say I had two fields as below

120m - 10- ATHENS - GA - 30606 - CHICAGO - IL - 60290 - 24000lbs - 48000lbs - FT

120m - 10- ATHENS - GA - 30606 - CHICAGO - IL - 60290 - 24000lbs - 48000lbs - SD

I would need this to be combined to

120m - 20 - ATHENS - GA - 30606 - CHICAGO - IL - 60290 - 24000lbs - 48000lbs - FT/SD - 50% FB - 50% SD

Or something along those lines.

Anything helps!

Thank you,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Consider an aggregate query where you group by the needed matched fields and have the records filtered by the two Equipment Types. Then, use conditional aggregate columns divided by total group count for the percentage breakdowns:

```
SELECT [Miles traveled], [Volume], [ID], [Origin City/State/Zip],
       [Destination City/State/Zip], [Min Weight], [Max Weight], 'FT/SD' AS [Equipment Type]
       SUM(IIF([Equipment Type] = 'FT', 1, NULL)) / COUNT(*) AS FT_PCT, 
       SUM(IIF([Equipment Type] = 'SD', 1, NULL)) / COUNT(*) AS SD_PCT    
FROM ShipmentTableName
WHERE [Equipment Type] IN ('FT', 'SD')
GROUP BY [Miles traveled], [Volume], [ID], [Origin City/State/Zip], 
         [Destination City/State/Zip], [Min Weight], [Max Weight]
```